# How are are NumPy's in-place operators implemented to explain the significant performance gain

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that in Python, the in-place operators use the `__iadd__` method for in-place operators. For immutable types, the `__iadd__` is a workaround using the `__add__`, e.g., like `tmp = a + b; a = tmp`, but mutable types (like lists) are modified in-place, which causes a slight speed boost.

However, if I have a NumPy array where I modify its contained immutable types, e.g., integers or floats, there is also an even more significant speed boost. How does this work? I did some example benchmarks below:

```
import numpy as np

def inplace(a, b):
    a += b
    return a

def assignment(a, b):
    a = a + b
    return a

int1 = 1
int2 = 1

list1 = [1]
list2 = [1]

npary1 = np.ones((1000,1000))
npary2 = np.ones((1000,1000))

print('Python integers')
%timeit inplace(int1, 1)
%timeit assignment(int2, 1)

print('\nPython lists')
%timeit inplace(list1, [1])
%timeit assignment(list2, [1])

print('\nNumPy Arrays')
%timeit inplace(npary1, 1)
%timeit assignment(npary2, 1)
```

What I would expect is a similar difference as for the Python integers when I used the in-place operators on NumPy arrays, however the results are completely different:

```
Python integers
1000000 loops, best of 3: 265 ns per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 249 ns per loop

Python lists
1000000 loops, best of 3: 449 ns per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 638 ns per loop

NumPy Arrays
100 loops, best of 3: 3.76 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each call to `assignment(npary2, 1)` requires creating a new one million element array. Consider how much time it takes just to allocate a (1000, 1000)-shaped array of ones:

```
In [21]: %timeit np.ones((1000, 1000))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.84 ms per loop
```

This allocation of a new temporary array requires on my machine about 3.84 ms, and is on the right order of magnitude to explain the entire difference between `inplace(npary1, 1)` and `assignment(nparay2, 1)`:

```
In [12]: %timeit inplace(npary1, 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit assignment(npary2, 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.04 ms per loop
```

So, given that allocation is a relatively slow process, it makes sense that in-place addition is significantly faster than assignment to a new array.

---

NumPy operations on NumPy arrays may be fast, but creation of NumPy arrays is relatively slow. Consider, for example, how much more time it takes to create a NumPy array than a Python list:

```
In [14]: %timeit list()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 106 ns per loop

In [15]: %timeit np.array([])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 563 ns per loop
```

This is one reason why it is generally better to use one large NumPy array (allocated once) rather than thousands of small NumPy arrays.